# Changing App Size Once Submitted to Android Market?

Tags: android, google-play

I am here to discuss a relatively strange question but if anyone knows the issue do help me please.

Recently I have developed an application and submitted to Android Market. The final apk file that was uploaded was of size 4.6 Mb or so. But when you see the app in Market...it shows the size of app to be 9Mb or so. Another strange thing is when you download the app from market it is of the same size of which was uploaded i.e. 4.6 Mb...I am unable to understand why in Market the size not being displayed accordingly. Please help if someone gets this riddle solved. Thanks!